# Disable databinding in MXML

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding, code-generation, flex4, mxml

When the Flex SDK converts MXML to actionscript it generates a lot of databinding code. Sometimes, however, I don't want to bind a variable, for example if I know the variable will not change.

I can't seem to find a work around in Flex to disable the autogenerated databinding.

Also, I was hoping this might also help with some of the runtime warnings thrown by databinding. 
To get around them, I sometimes use the following, which only throws syntax warnings (and don't appear in my console at runtime). 

Syntax warning: 
Data binding will not be able to detect changes when using square bracket operator.  For Array, please use ArrayCollection.getItemAt() instead.

Answer (score 3):

The following tag will tell Flex SDK that variable do not really change and remove "Unable to bind ..." warnings:

```
[Bindable("__NoChangeEvent__")]
private var model:MyModel = MyModel.instance;
```

Next, move `array[i]`-like expressions to a separate function in order to remove warnings. If you had this:

```
<mx:Button label="{array[i]}"/>
```

Then create a function:

```
private function buttonLabel(i):String
{
    return array[i];
}
```

And the MXML:

```
<mx:Button label="{buttonLabel(i)}"/>
```

P.S: If button label changes in runtime then you can add `[Bindable(...)]` metatags to the function:

```
[Bindable("stringsChange")]
private function buttonLabel(i):String
{
    return array[i];
}

dispatchEvent(new Event("stringsChange"));
```